# How to (auto) list all route to Swagger UI (swagger-ui-express)

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I've made node.js REST API project, and I want to use *swagger-ui-express* for document them...

The problem is, I want to listing all my routes from my REST API project to show on my swagger page, but I got message: ***No operations defined in spec!***.

If anyone could tell me the right way to configure/setting up swagger-ui-express for listing all my routes?

*Here my code*

```
//---app.js---
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const firstRoute = require('./routes/first');
const secondRoute = require('./routes/second');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//...
//ADD SWAGGER & ROUTES
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
var options = {
    explorer: true,
    apis: ['./routes/*.js']
};
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
app.use('/first', firstRoute);
app.use('/second', secondRoute);
app.use((req, res, next) => {res.status(404).json({ message: 'Page not found' });});
//...
app.listen(3000);
```

```
//---swagger.json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "TITLE",
    "description": "Description",
    "license": {
      "name": ""
      "url": ""
    }
  }
}
```

```
//---routes/first.js
const express = require('express');
const FirstController = require('../controllers/First');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', userController.getFirsts);
router.post('/',userController.createFirst);

module.exports = router;
```

```
//---controllers/first.js
const { First } = require('../infrastructures/sequelize');

exports.getFirsts = (req, res, next) => {
    //Some logic
    return res.status(200).json({...})
};
exports.createFirst= (req, res, next) => {
    //Some logic
    return res.status(200).json({...})
};
```

*-Assume that routes/seconde.js similar to routes/first.js
and controllers/second.js similar to controllers/first.js*

Comment: It will not auto list, you have to list into your swagger.json file or use [swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) for annotation writing..

Answer (score 0):

I think i've seen an npm package called [swagger-express-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-express-middleware) which, i recall correctly, intercepts requests and maps them to the swagger file.

The only thing i certainly know that "automaps" OApiSpec2-3 by effectively saving requests/responses made to a working API endpoint, is the [Swagger Inspector](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-inspector/), but as you will quickly notice, that power comes with an associated cost.